# why isn't this base64 string decoding?

Tags: php, base64, libsodium

My code:

```php
<?php

$a = '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';

echo strlen(base64_decode($a)) . "\n\n";
echo strlen(sodium_base642bin($a, SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL_NO_PADDING));
```

`base64_decode` decodes that string just fine but `sodium_base642bin` fails, regardless of what the `$id` parameter is (SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL, SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_ORIGINAL_NO_PADDING, SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE and SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE_NO_PADDING). More specifically, `sodium_base642bin` throws the following (useless) exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SodiumException: sodium_base642bin(): Argument #1 ($string) must be a valid base64 string
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of your echo statement?

Comment: @MikeStratton - the first echo statement gives 1491 as the output. The second one throws an exception.

Comment: @MikeStratton - see https://php.net/sodium-base642bin . If you want further assistance installing libsodium I recommend you post a new SO question

Comment: Interesting question, to say the least. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is most likely due to filtering done by the `base64_decode` method. If you look at the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) you can see that `strict` defaults to `false` which will filter out non-base64 characters (see: sanitise). If you set the second argument to `true`, your first string will return `false`.

Comment: @Rylee - if there was an invalid character I'd expect https://base64.guru/tools/validator to identify that invalid character. If I add a `&` to the middle of the string I get a `The following characters are not suitable for the specified standard: &` from that tool. So what's wrong with the base64 string I'm trying to decode? If it's an invalid character then what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in a comment by @Rylee, your base64 string is malformed. Since `base64_decode` tends to ignore some errors by working in non-strict mode by default, it does'nt fail. But by setting the `strict` parameter to `true`, the function will return `false`.

To check whats going wrong, you can use a tool like this [base64 validator](https://base64.guru/tools/validator), it will say that it's invalid, and even propose you to repair it.

Once repaired, if you diff char by char the result with your encoded string, you find out that the last character `S` must be removed in order to get a fully valid base64 encoded string.